# Can AWS App-Sync be used without dynamoDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-appsync

I am interested in the offline and sync capabilities of Amazon's app-sync but I was wondering if it could be used without dynamoDB as the backend.  The graphQL resolvers written in VTL for dynamoDB look atrocious. It seems it would be much nicer to use a mongo backend.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can use AppSync without DynamoDB. You can use ElasticSearch out of the box (you will need to provision the ES cluster and then setup the resolvers) or you can use Lambda and pipe your data to any source, such as mySQL. Here's info on ElasticSearch:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-elasticsearch-resolvers.html

Comment: What about using mongodb?

Comment: You can use any DB by making Lambda as your resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Yes aws appsync can be used without dynamodb . In datasource section of your appsync module you can see options to which you want to link your appsync module. Even don't worry about schema generation. Appsync help you to do it automatically . Just enable auto generate schema .
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorials.html